# Set of primes $p_{1}\equiv 3 \bmod p_{2}$ such that $\phi(2^{\frac{{p_1}-3}{p_2}}-1)\equiv 0 \bmod p_1$ with $p_1,p_2\equiv 3\bmod 4$?

Tags: prime-numbers, gaussian, congruences, arithmetic-functions

let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be positive primes such that  $p_1,p_2 \equiv 3\bmod 4$ 
 and $\phi$ is the Euler totiont function , I want to find the Set of primes  $p_{1}\equiv 3 \bmod p_{2}$ such that $\phi(2^{\frac{{p_1}-3}{p_2}}-1)\equiv 0 \bmod p_1$ ? I can't find such pairs satisfying the titled claim , I have used the fact that : $\phi(2^{\frac{{p_1}-3}{p_2}}-1)\equiv 0 \bmod \frac{{p_1}-3}{p_2}$ but this dosn't give any thing to determine all pairs $(p_1,p_2)$ for which the titled claim w'd be satisfied .

**Edit** I have Edited the question to avoid any complication and working with ordinary  prime which are $3$ modulo $4$ in the same time gives the definition of Gaussian primes

**Note**:The motivation of this question is to know more about behavior of Euler totiont function with Gaussian primes

Comment: If $\frac{|z_1|-1}{|z_2|}$ is an integer, then $|z_{1}|\equiv 1 \bmod|z_{2}|$.

Comment: primes of which form?

Comment: @FedorPetrov primes of the form $z= b i$  (Gaussian primes) , I have montioned that

Comment: Why not just ordinary primes congruent to 3 mod 4, but multiplied by $i$?

Comment: Multiplied by i beacuse I meant Gaussian prime and it works also as you claimed

Comment: @FedorPetrov, Ok since it works as all positive primes which are 3 mod 4 are Gaussian I think I can edit the question just I take primes such that conguent to 3 mod 4